# Unusual Behavior in Magento 2.4.4 Commerce: Editable Address Gets Added as New Data After Successful Checkout

Tags: checkout, address, magento-2-commerce, magento-commerce

I am investigating a bug that is occurring in a Magento 2.4.4 Commerce project.

The bug occurs when the following steps are performed:

- Editing an address on my profile page.
- Checking out by selecting any shipping address.
- After the checkout is completed, whether it is successful or not, a new address record, as edited above, suddenly appears in the customer_address_entity table.
- The columns **default_billing** and **default_shipping** in the **customer_entity** table now contain the values of the newly created address record.

I have attempted various debugging methods to identify the cause of this issue. Initially, I added a log to the file extended from `Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement`. The file path is `GShop\Ipay88Epp\Plugin\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement`. However, it became apparent that the address was already created before this point.

Subsequently, I attempted debugging by adding logs inside the vendor file located at `Magento\Checkout\Model\PaymentInformationManagement` for testing purposes. The logs indicated that the redundant address was not created only during the construct phase; rather, it was being stored throughout various functions.

I also explored other troubleshooting techniques, such as checking if the customer address list is accessed when the customer clicks on place-order.js through an Ajax call. However, I encountered an issue where the called link appeared to be a not found URL.

Additionally, I attempted to add an observer, but it seemed that the event observer was not being triggered. The events I tried were **checkout_submit_all_after** and **sales_order_save_after**.